# How do I check when a fb-token will expire

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

is there a possibility to check when a fb-token will expire?

I've read [Authenticating as an app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) and [Handling invalid and expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/) and searched the interwebs for an answer but I couldn't find any.

Regards, Senad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is, there's an endpoint for it now.

You can retrieve the information related to a particular Access Token by issuing a GET request to the `debug_token` connection. Something like:

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

You can get more information about it in the [Getting Info about Tokens and Debugging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling) reference.

Comment: That "Getting Info about Tokens and Debugging" link is broken now, I think this is the current page: [Access Tokens: Debugging and Error Handling](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling). And it doesn't specify, but to get a response, for a page access token, at least, I repeated the same token value for both `input_token` _and_ `access_token`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no specific endpoint that will tell you if an `access_token` is still valid or not, but you can use the token to fetch anything and see if it return an error or not.

However if you are using the server side flow for authentication, they will send you an `expire` parameters that will hold the time in seconds that the token will remain valid (the sdk may hide this fact from you).

But as the [Handling invalid access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#errors) page explains, there's a number of reasons why an access_token can go invalid so the expire field alone won't be able to tell you if the token is valid at the moment or not, so the only way to find out is to try using it and see if its returns an error, as the Handling expired... page states, you will have to be prepared for any graph request return errors.

Comment: thanks... not the answer I wanted to hear but thats what I thought in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check it here for a given access token:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug